# Is there a function in matlab to calculate higher level of DCT's like DCT-III,IV?

Tags: matlab, transform, trigonometry, dct, discrete

I have recently started working with DCT. I have started with DCT-II, and there is dct() & dct2() in MATLAB that helps in the calculated of 1-D and 2-D DCT-II respectively. I wanted to know if there are some other functions that help in the calculations of higher level of DCT, like III or IV.

Comment: The number indicates a different definition, not a "higher level". DCT-III is not better than DCT-II, it is just different. DCT-II is the most commonly used one in image processing.

Comment: i just realized the poster actually meant 3 and 4 dimensions matricies, not the famous DCT3 and DCT4 algorithms ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, the [`dct`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/dct.html) function has a `Type` argument that accepts 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 , so you can use it .

```matlab
dct(x,n,dim,'Type',3)
```

**Edit:** it just hit me that the author is asking for 3 and 4 dimension DCT, not the DCT3 and DCT4 algorithms ...
well, there isn't but it's not too hard to implement, a 2D DCT is just doing DCT on 2 dimensions, hence a 3D DCT would look like this

```matlab
result = dct(x,n1,1);
result = dct(result,n2,2);
result = dct(result,n3,3);
```